# Formula to convert QND95 to EPSG:4326

Tags: convert, wgs84

I have coordinates in [QND95 (Qatar National Grid)](http://www.epsg-registry.org/export.htm?wkt=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::2932) and I need to convert it to WGS84, specifically EPSG:4326. There are already many tools available for this, but the problem is I want to use the conversion in my mobile application.

So basically I'd like to know how to convert QND95 to WGS84, any formula to transform them, which I can use in my application.

Comment: By WGS84 do you mean EPSG:4326, CRS:84 or something else?

Comment: What tools have you found, and why aren't they applicable to your mobile application?  Are you looking to code a solution or are you looking for a tool?  If you want to code, what language. What is your data.   Please edit your question to add more details.

Comment: Basically I'm just looking for formula, and by WGS84 I mean EPSG:4326
Thanks

Comment: [IOGP Guidance Note 7 part 2: Coordinate Conversions and Transformations including Formulas](https://www.iogp.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/373-07-02.pdf)